# Including a module in a Rails 5 Application Record class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Application Record to simplify shared logic throughout an application.

Here's an example that writes a scope for a boolean and its inverse. This works well:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.boolean_scope(attr, opposite = nil)
    scope(attr, -> { where("#{attr}": true) })
    scope(opposite, -> { where("#{attr}": false) }) if opposite.present?
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  boolean_scope :verified, :unverified
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  boolean_scope :sent, :pending
end
```

My Application Record class got long enough it made sense for me to break it up into individual modules and load those as needed.

Here's my attempted solution:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  include ScopeHelpers
end

module ScopeHelpers
  def self.boolean_scope(attr, opposite = nil)
    scope(attr, -> { where("#{attr}": true) })
    scope(opposite, -> { where("#{attr}": false) }) if opposite.present?
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  boolean_scope :verified, :unverified
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  boolean_scope :sent, :pending
end
```

In this case, I don't get a load error, but `boolean_scope` is then undefined on `User` and `Message`.

Is there a way to ensure the included modules are loaded at the appropriate time and available to Application Record and its inheriting models?

---

I've also attempted to have the models include the modules directly and that did not fix the issue.

```
module ScopeHelpers
  def self.boolean_scope(attr, opposite = nil)
    scope(attr, -> { where("#{attr}": true) })
    scope(opposite, -> { where("#{attr}": false) }) if opposite.present?
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  include ScopeHelpers
  boolean_scope :verified, :unverified
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  include ScopeHelpers
  boolean_scope :sent, :pending
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative to @Pavan's answer, you can do this:

```
module ScopeHelpers
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern # to handle ClassMethods submodule

  module ClassMethods
    def boolean_scope(attr, opposite = nil)
      scope(attr, -> { where(attr => true) })
      scope(opposite, -> { where(attr => false) }) if opposite.present?
    end
  end
end

# then use it as usual
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ScopeHelpers
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

> In this case, I don't get a load error, but boolean_scope is then
>   undefined on User and Message

The problem is `include` add methods on an *instance of a class*. You need to use `extend`

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  extend ScopeHelpers
end
```

Now you can call it like `User.boolean_scope`. Below is the example for *include vs extend*

```
module Foo
  def foo
    puts 'heyyyyoooo!'
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

Bar.new.foo # heyyyyoooo!
Bar.foo # NoMethodError: undefined method ‘foo’ for Bar:Class

class Baz
  extend Foo
end

Baz.foo # heyyyyoooo!
Baz.new.foo # NoMethodError: undefined method ‘foo’ for #<Baz:0x1e708>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `User` and `Message` classes don't seem to be inheriting `ApplicationRecord`. How will they have access to `::boolean_scope`?

Try this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  boolean_scope :verified, :unverified
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  boolean_scope :sent, :pending
end
```

Comment: Good catch. Unfortunately, the models were inheriting Application Record. The problem, AFAIK, doesn't seem to be related to inheritance, as I also tried including the module directly. and that did not work. I've updated the question.