# How to properly customize/extend ApplicationRecord behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add some customized behavior to all my Rails models globally without having to include/extend within each model file.

I tried doing this inside an initializer in config/initializers/virtual_column.rb:

```
module VirtualColumns
  #becomes a class-level function on any ApplicationRecord
  def virtual_column ...
    ...
  end 
end

module VirtualColumnChecker
  #becomes an instance function on any ApplicationRecord
  def check_virtual_columns! 
    ...
  end
end

#I've tried making this work in the on_load callback, but the callback doesn't seem to execute?
#ApplicationSupport.on_load(:active_record) do 
    ApplicationRecord.extend VirtualColumns
    ApplicationRecord.include VirtualColumnChecker
#end
```

What ends up happening is it works when I start the server, but after I make a change to one of my app files, the rails engine's hot reloading doesn't re-run the initializer.  The class-level call to virtual_column throws a "no function defined" error.  Restarting the server makes it work again.  I'm sure this is normal behavior though; I'm thinking the initializers should just run once at startup, and not when the engine hot reloads.

My question is:
Where is the proper place to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Maybe have these modules as `concern`s instead of adding them in the initializers?

Comment: Perhaps this SO article will be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498962/including-a-module-in-a-rails-5-application-record-class